# SQL Union exclude row if value already exists in first table

Tags: t-sql, duplicates, unions

I have two tables which i wish to combine.  However, there is a field in both tables that should have the same value in the second table the second tables record should be excluded.

These are a MSSQL 2012 tables.

The only way i can think of is something nasty like this.

Select A, B
from Tab1
Union
Select C, D 
from Tab2
where Tab2.c  not in (Select A from Tab1)

It looks relatively clean in my example but the selects for Tab1 and tab2 have long and complex where clauses and i would need to duplicated that in the "not in" select statement.

I've seen other solutions but not in MSSQL.  Any one out there have a better example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well in t-sql i use this kind of code

```
USE tempdb
GO
CREATE TABLE StudentDetails
(
StudentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
StudentName VARCHAR(15)
)
GO
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(1,'SMITH')
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(2,'ALLEN')
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(3,'JONES')
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(4,'MARTIN')
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(5,'JAMES')
GO
CREATE TABLE StudentTotalMarks
(
StudentID INTEGER REFERENCES StudentDetails,
StudentMarks INTEGER
)
GO
INSERT INTO StudentTotalMarks
VALUES(1,230)
INSERT INTO StudentTotalMarks
VALUES(2,255)
INSERT INTO StudentTotalMarks
VALUES(3,200)
GO
-- Select from Table
SELECT *
FROM StudentDetails
GO
SELECT *
FROM StudentTotalMarks
GO
-- Merge Statement
MERGE StudentTotalMarks AS stm
USING (SELECT StudentID,StudentName FROM StudentDetails) AS sd
ON stm.StudentID = sd.StudentID
WHEN MATCHED AND stm.StudentMarks > 250 THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET stm.StudentMarks = stm.StudentMarks + 25
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(StudentID,StudentMarks)
VALUES(sd.StudentID,25);
GO
-- Select from Table
SELECT *
FROM StudentDetails
GO
SELECT *
FROM StudentTotalMarks
GO
-- Clean up
DROP TABLE StudentDetails
GO
DROP TABLE StudentTotalMarks
GO
```

The Merge Join performs very well and the following result is obtained. 
http://www.pinaldave.com/bimg/MergeStatement.gif

Hope this helps